# MySQL выборка и подстановка элемента из другой таблицы

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеется 2 таблицы: 
1-ая - companies

| id | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 5 |
| 4 | 7 |
| 5 | 7 |

2-ая - comments

| id | company_id (внешний ключ companies - id) | comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | Тест 1 |
| 2 | 3 | Тест 2 |
| 3 | 4 | Тест 3 |
| 4 | 4 | Тест 4 |
| 5 | 5 | Тест 5 |

Пытаюсь создать выборку companies + последний комментарий (по ID) для компании следующим образом:

```
SELECT
  `companies`.`id` AS `id`,
  `companies`.`user_id ` AS `user_id `,
  `comments`.`comment` AS `last_comment`
FROM
  `companies`
  JOIN `comments`
WHERE
  `companies`.`user_id` = '7'
  AND `comments`.`id` = (
    SELECT
      MAX(`comments`.`id`)
    FROM
      `comments`
      JOIN `companies`
    WHERE
      `comments`.`company_id` = `companies`.`id`
  )
ORDER BY
  `companies`.`id` DESC
```

В теории должно выдавать:

| id | user_id | last_comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 7 | Тест 4 |
| 5 | 7 | Тест 5 |

Но выдает:

| id | user_id | last_comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 7 | Тест 5 |
| 5 | 7 | Тест 5 |

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить данную головоломку

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  c.id AS id,
  c.user_id AS user_id,
  (
    SELECT
      comment
    FROM
      comments
    WHERE
      company_id = c.id
    ORDER BY
      id DESC
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS last_comment
FROM
  companies c
WHERE
  c.user_id = '7'
ORDER BY
  c.id DESC;
```

Comment: А почему сортировка DESC?

Comment: Все получилось! Спасибо Вам большое!